# Why the if statement continuing while the first condition is true

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, return

I have this program where a user will give 3 inputs. Comparing the inputs the program will return the biggest number. When a user give an input where the third number greater than the second number but the first number is the biggest number it gives a result that the third number is the biggest. But it should give the result that the first number is the biggest.

```
def max_num(x,y,z):
    x = input("num_1")
    y = input("num_2")
    z = input("num_3")
    
    if x > y and x > z:
        return(x + "is the biggest number")
    elif y > x and y > z:
        return(y + " is the biggest number")
    else:
        return(z + " is the biggest number")
        
        
print(max_num("num_1", "num_2", "num_3"))
```

[image]

Comment: ``input`` reads *strings* – *the string* `"9"` is indeed larger than *the string* `"678"`, since its first character is larger.

Comment: ```int(input("Num 1"))```. This will do. Repeat it for your other inputs

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to convert your objects of type `str` to `int`:

```
    x = int(input("num_1"))
    y = int(input("num_2"))
    z = int(input("num_3"))
```

You can even eliminate the use of the `and` keyword, and just use multiple operators on the variables. Finally, you don't need the `elif` and `else` statements; the `return` calls already ensure that only one of the three lines may be executed:

```
def max_num(x,y,z):
    x = int(input(x))
    y = int(input(y))
    z = int(input(z))
    
    if z < x > y:
        return f"{x} is the biggest number"
    if z < y > x:
        return f"{y} is the biggest number"
    return f"{z} is the biggest number"
            
print(max_num("num_1", "num_2", "num_3"))
```

Note the f-string. With `x`, `y` and `z` converted to integers, you won't be able to concatenate them with strings using the `+` operator anymore, unless you utilize the `str()` wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Python has an inbuilt `max` function
You can re-write your function something like this

```
def max_num(x,y,z):
    x = int(input(x))
    y = int(input(y))
    z = int(input(z))
    return f"{max(x, y, z)} is the biggest number"
```